# Инициализация параметров структуры Си

Tags: c, структуры

Столкнулся с инициализацией полей структуры в Си:

```
void func() {
    struct {
        int var1;
        int var2;
    } OB = {
          .var1 = 10,
          .var2 = 15
      };
 // код функции
}
```

Visual Studio 2017 отказывается компилировать этот код, выдавая синтаксическую ошибку в месте, где идёт инициализация параметров структуры. Это, вроде как, С99. Как исправить, чтобы VS не ругался на данное объявление?

Comment: Включить поддержку Си в свойствах проекта: Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As.

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируйте просто, без имен полей:

```
struct {
    int var1;
    int var2;
} OB = { 10, 15 };
```

Только вот - какой версией вы пользуетесь? С какими ключиками? Точно ли вы работаете в режиме C, а не C++? потому что на самом деле VC++2017 спокойно компилирует ваш код...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, работаю в режиме Си. В итоге действительно помогло включение компиляции в настройках проекта в режиме Си.

Answer (score 0):

Это код на языке С и компилировать его нужно как код на языке С. Visual Studio 2017 не отказывается компилировать этот код.

Comment: Да-да, всё верно, спасибо.